# How do I find out what version of Sybase is running

Tags: version, sap-ase

I would like to know the exact version of Sybase currently running on my machine.

Please let me know how to get this info?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There are two ways to know the about Sybase version,

1) Using this System procedure to get the information about Sybase version

```
> sp_version
> go
```

2) Using this command to get Sybase version

```
> select @@version
> go
```

Answer (score 17):

Run this command:

```
select @@version
```

Answer (score 5):

1)From OS level(UNIX):-

```
dataserver -v
```

2)From Syabse isql:-

```
select @@version
go

sp_version
go
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running below command (Works on both windows and linux)

```
isql -v
```